# How to change color of Camera LED / Flashlight in Android

Tags: android, android-camera, camera-flash

I'm trying to change color of Camera LED / Flashlight in Android. is their any way to achieve this ?

I know we can change colors on Nexus One Track Ball. I'm trying to change Camera LED / Flashlight color in Android like that.

Answer (score 12):

> I'm trying to change color of Camera LED / Flashlight in Android. is their any way to achieve this ?

Tape a piece of colored transparent plastic over the LED.

> I'm trying to change Camera LED / Flashlight color in Android like that.

There is nothing in the Android SDK for this.

You are welcome to try to find some Android device that has a camera flash that uses different colors, then contact the manufacturer of that device to see if they exposed some SDK add-on to give apps control over that color. Out of several hundred million Android devices, there are approximately zero that offer this capability.