# How to flash a back flash light with different color?

Tags: android, flashlight

Hy I am working on flashing a back flash light in different color. First I have worked on flashing the back light on a certain conditions such as download complete . But Now I want to handle the download interrupt or handling the error . And I want to show the error by flashing the different color of a back flash light . Is it possible.?
if yes then please share me a code here.

Bundle of thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change color of Camera LED / Flashlight in Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17898035/how-to-change-color-of-camera-led-flashlight-in-android)

Answer (score 1):

You can't change the color of the camera flash, but some devices have a notification light. Maybe try flashing the notification light on certain errors.

Comment: CAN you please explain a little what is notification light ? that must be a screen flash ?

Answer (score 0):

There is no way way you can do that using SDK. Can you change color of your Tubelight in your room? Even if there are devices with multicolor LEDs, I don't think device manufacturers expose an open SDK for developers to use it.

Comment: As Mark says in this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17898035/how-to-change-color-of-camera-led-flashlight-in-android you could tape a piece of color transparent polythene to achieve this :)